# German (Switzerland) German (Austria) on App Store Connect - Release Notes

Tags: ios, localization, app-store, app-store-connect

I have an app localized for 3 variants of German:

1. German `de-DE`
2. German (Switzerland) `de-CH`
3. German (Austria) `de-AT`

In the project navigator I'm able to see all the three variants, also the app successfully switches the language to any of those and runs the appropriate version.

However, I'm unable to post release notes and see only the "German" option.

Is it an intentional behavior of App Store Connect or the service doesn't recognize the languages enabled for the app and doesn't show them for release notes?

[image: Project file]

[image: app store connect]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The localisation options shown for the App Store meta data is a fixed list.  They are not determined by the localisations in your app.

Where their aren't country specific options then I assume that the language that is shown to the user accessing the App Store is determined by the language setting on their device.

Someone with de-CH will see German while someone with fr-CH will see French.

Interestingly there are options for French (France) and French (Canada) as well as English (UK), English (USA) and English (Australia).

I guess you would need to ask Apple why they don't provide variations for Austria, Germany and Switzerland.